# Trying to improve slow query by adding indexes in MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

For the following query I have tried creating an index for `row_id, created_in, updated_in` as well as `entity_id, row_id, created_in, updated_in`. In both cases, the index is ignored.

```
SELECT 
      e.entity_id
   FROM
      catalog_product_super_link l
         INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity e
            ON e.row_id = l.parent_id
            AND e.created_in <= 2147483647 
            AND e.updated_in > 1
   WHERE
      l.product_id IN (5528, 5529, 5530, 5531, 5532, 5533, 5534, 5535, 5540, 5541)
```

(For readability, only use `tick` marks such as columns that might be reserved words like `date`, `column`, etc.)

`EXPLAIN` reports that my keys are possible, but it opts for `Using where`

In production, the product)id `IN` list can be much larger.

Comment: what's the table structure and fields type?

Comment: Since `entity_id` is not used as search criteria, an index starting with it will not help and index that helps the search and ends with `entity_id` could though. _If an index "covers" a field, a query can complete without needing to hit the table data directly._

Answer (score 0):

I'd create (`row_id`) or (`row_id`, `entity_id`) on `catalog_product_entity` table and (`product_id`, `row_id`) on `catalog_product_super_link` table.

Not sure if `created_in` and `updated_in` should be included in the first index as I do not know how many rows can be filtered with provided criteria.

As per EXPLAIN results (usually it is a good idea to provide one in question), in many cases optimizer (and EXPLAIN) will choose different plans based on data/statistics you have. If tables only have ~100 rows each, it is faster to get all data and filter it in-place than use index => data lookups.

So you should populate your DB with a bit realistic data before trying to optimize based on EXPLAIN results.

Answer (score 0):

To help the Optimizer start with `e`,

```
e: INDEX(created_in), INDEX(updated_in)
l: INDEX(parent_id, product_id)
```

To help the Optimizer start with `l`,

```
l: INDEX(product_id, parent_id)   -- in this order
e: INDEX(row_id, created_in), INDEX(row_id, updated_in)
```

More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this query, the outermost limit is based on your Product_ID from the Catalog_Product_Super_Link, but also using the Parent_ID joining to the Catalog_Product_Entity.  Having individual columns on each of the columns wont help as much.

I would have (and in this specific order )

```
table                        index
Catalog_Product_Super_Link   (product_id, parent_id)
catalog_product_entity       (row_id, updated_in, created_in )
```

I could conditionally swap the last two in catalog product entity as you give no cardinality to the values for updated_in and created_in.  My IMPRESSION is that by looking for anything having an Updated_in > 1 means it MUST have been updated.  But is this some date-based offset integer value or what?  So if you have a million records and only 50k have been updated, your obviously working with the smaller set first.  For created_in, what is the basis of that number too.